# Query a list of value of a specific column in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I'm trying to query a list as an array directly out of a table of my database without having to create another foreach loop and construct one myself.

---

I try

```
return Response::json(Skill::select('name')->get());
```

I get

```
[{"name":"Vagrant"},{"name":"Docker"},{"name":"Gulp"},{"name":"Heroku"},{"name":"RequireJS"},{"name":"AngularJS"},{"name":"Composer "},{"name":"NPM"},{"name":"MySQL"},{"name":"Sublime Text"},{"name":"Laravel"},{"name":"PyCharm"},{"name":"Mac OS X"},{"name":"Windows"},{"name":"Ubuntu"},{"name":"Cent OS"},{"name":"Photoshop"},{"name":"Illustrator"},{"name":"MobaXTerm"},{"name":"Terminal"},{"name":"iMovie"},{"name":"Final Cut"},{"name":"GitHub"},{"name":"BitBucket"},{"name":"Selenium"},{"name":"Python"},{"name":"Bower"},{"name":"Sass"},{"name":"Digital Ocean"},{"name":"Linode"},{"name":"Siteground"},{"name":"Go Daddy"},{"name":"Shopify"},{"name":"Facebook"},{"name":"Twitter"},{"name":"Salesforce"},{"name":"OAuth 2.0"},{"name":"SAML 2.0"},{"name":"OpenID Connect"},{"name":"PostgreSQL"},{"name":"Bash"},{"name":"PHP"},{"name":"Google Map"},{"name":"Google Translation"},{"name":"Instagram"},{"name":"LESS"},{"name":"Geolocation API"},{"name":"Xcode"},{"name":"Atom"},{"name":"Webpack"},{"name":"AWS Console"},{"name":"Secure Shell"},{"name":"Node"},{"name":"Yarn"},{"name":"Pod"},{"name":"EC2"},{"name":"Amazon ECS"},{"name":"S3"},{"name":"Amazon RDS"},{"name":"Camtasia"},{"name":"Core Data"},{"name":"Realm"},{"name":"VS Code"},{"name":"TextMate"},{"name":"TextWrangler"},{"name":"Laravel Elixir"},{"name":"Virtual Machine"},{"name":"Open  Stack"},{"name":"Redis"},{"name":"Local Storage"},{"name":"Protractor"},{"name":"Jest"},{"name":"Mocha"},{"name":"Chai"},{"name":"SinonJS"},{"name":"AWS"},{"name":"HTML"},{"name":"CSS"},{"name":"Javascript"},{"name":"Sketch"},{"name":"iOS"},{"name":"Express"},{"name":"Angular"},{"name":"React Native"},{"name":"jQuery"},{"name":"Nginx"},{"name":"Apache"},{"name":"PayPal"},{"name":"Square "},{"name":"Disqus"},{"name":"YouTube"},{"name":"Swagger"},{"name":"GitLab"},{"name":"Amazon ECR "},{"name":"Jira"},{"name":"Trello "},{"name":"Evernote "},{"name":"Confluence "},{"name":"Word"},{"name":"CodeBox"},{"name":"Markdown"},{"name":"Noteability"},{"name":"Kamar"},{"name":"Jasmine"},{"name":"Swift"},{"name":"Coda"},{"name":"Postman"},{"name":"Wireshark"},{"name":"Transmit"},{"name":"WinSCP"},{"name":"Navicat Premium"},{"name":"Kaleidoscope"},{"name":"Mind Note "},{"name":"Divvy"},{"name":"Duet"},{"name":"Draw.io"},{"name":"Google Draw"},{"name":"VMWare Fusion "},{"name":"Virtualbox"},{"name":"QuickBooks"},{"name":"Chat.io"},{"name":"FusionCharts"},{"name":"Google Chart"},{"name":"J Player"},{"name":"CKEditor"}]
```

I was trying to get these

```
["Vagrant","Docker","Gulp","Heroku","RequireJS","AngularJS","Composer ","NPM","MySQL","Sublime Text","Laravel","PyCharm","Mac OS X","Windows","Ubuntu","Cent OS","Photoshop","Illustrator","MobaXTerm","Terminal","iMovie","Final Cut","GitHub","BitBucket","Selenium","Python","Bower","Sass","Digital Ocean","Linode","Siteground","Go Daddy","Shopify","Facebook","Twitter","Salesforce","OAuth 2.0","SAML 2.0","OpenID Connect","PostgreSQL","Bash","PHP","Google Map","Google Translation","Instagram","LESS","Geolocation API","Xcode","Atom","Webpack","AWS Console","Secure Shell","Node","Yarn","Pod","EC2","Amazon ECS","S3","Amazon RDS","Camtasia","Core Data","Realm","VS Code","TextMate","TextWrangler","Laravel Elixir","Virtual Machine","Open  Stack","Redis","LocalStorage","Protractor","Jest","Mocha","Chai","SinonJS","AWS","HTML","CSS","Javascript","Sketch","iOS","Express","Angular","React Native","jQuery","Nginx","Apache","PayPal","Square ","Disqus","YouTube","Swagger","GitLab","Amazon ECR ","Jira","Trello ","Evernote ","Confluence ","Word","CodeBox","Markdown","Noteability","Kamar","Jasmine","Swift","Coda","Postman","Wireshark","Transmit","WinSCP","Navicat Premium","Kaleidoscope","Mind Note ","Divvy","Duet","Draw.io","Google Draw","VMWare Fusion ","Virtualbox","QuickBooks","Chat.io","FusionCharts","Google Chart","J Player","CKEditor"]
```

How would one go about debugging this further?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got it..

`return Skill::all()->pluck('name');`

seems to return what I am looking for.

```
[
    "Vagrant",
    "Docker",
    "Gulp",
    "Heroku",
    "RequireJS",
    "AngularJS",
    "Composer ",
    "NPM",
    "MySQL",
    "Sublime Text",
    "Laravel",
    "PyCharm",
    "Mac OS X",
    "Windows",
    "Ubuntu",
    "Cent OS",
    "Photoshop",
    "Illustrator",
    "MobaXTerm",
    "Terminal",
    "iMovie",
    "Final Cut",
    "GitHub",
    "BitBucket",
    "Selenium",
    "Python",
    "Bower",
    "Sass",
    "Digital Ocean",
    "Linode",
    "Siteground",
    "Go Daddy",
    "Shopify",
    "Facebook",
    "Twitter",
    "Salesforce",
    "OAuth 2.0",
    "SAML 2.0",
    "OpenID Connect",
    "PostgreSQL",
    "Bash",
    "PHP",
    "Google Map",
    "Google Translation",
    "Instagram",
    "LESS",
    "Geolocation API",
    "Xcode",
    "Atom",
    "Webpack",
    "AWS Console",
    "Secure Shell",
    "Node",
    "Yarn",
    "Pod",
    "EC2",
    "Amazon ECS",
    "S3",
    "Amazon RDS",
    "Camtasia",
    "Core Data",
    "Realm",
    "VS Code",
    "TextMate",
    "TextWrangler",
    "Laravel Elixir",
    "Virtual Machine",
    "Open  Stack",
    "Redis",
    "Local Storage",
    "Protractor",
    "Jest",
    "Mocha",
    "Chai",
    "SinonJS",
    "AWS",
    "HTML",
    "CSS",
    "Javascript",
    "Sketch",
    "iOS",
    "Express",
    "Angular",
    "React Native",
    "jQuery",
    "Nginx",
    "Apache",
    "PayPal",
    "Square ",
    "Disqus",
    "YouTube",
    "Swagger",
    "GitLab",
    "Amazon ECR ",
    "Jira",
    "Trello ",
    "Evernote ",
    "Confluence ",
    "Word",
    "CodeBox",
    "Markdown",
    "Noteability",
    "Kamar",
    "Jasmine",
    "Swift",
    "Coda",
    "Postman",
    "Wireshark",
    "Transmit",
    "WinSCP",
    "Navicat Premium",
    "Kaleidoscope",
    "Mind Note ",
    "Divvy",
    "Duet",
    "Draw.io",
    "Google Draw",
    "VMWare Fusion ",
    "Virtualbox",
    "QuickBooks",
    "Chat.io",
    "FusionCharts",
    "Google Chart",
    "J Player",
    "CKEditor"
]
```

Comment: you can use `Skill::pluck('name')`. It is select anly name field